# Constructors giving me an headache Java

Tags: java, methods, constructor, instance-variables, displayobject

Alright I'm stuck on 4 & 5 haven't started 6 yet. Not looking for anybody to do them just would like some help on finishing up 4 & 5 and possibly give any feedback on the code so far.

2. Create Instance Variables (attributes)
   Create at least 3privateinstance fields (attributes) for your class
   You must use at least 3 different data types for your fields
3. Create getter (accessor) and setter (mutator) methods
   Create a getter (accessor) method for each of your instance variables
   Create a setter (mutator) method for each of your instance variables
4. Create a Method to display your data
   Create a method called display, that simply prints out the values of all instance variables of your object
5. Create 2 Constructors
   Create a default constructor (no parameters) that assigns all your instance variables to default values
   Create a parameterized constructor that takes all instance variables as parameters, and sets the instance variables to the values provided by the parameters
6. Testing your program
   Create a class called Demo.java. This class will contain your main method
   Create an instance of your class by using the default constructor.
   Call all your objects set methods to assign values to your object
   Call the objects display method, to print out it's values
   Create another instance of your class by using the parameterized constructor
   Call the objects display method, to print out it's values

   ```
   public class Coffee {

   //Instance Variables        
       private double sugar;
       private int milk;
       private boolean heat; 

   //Constructor       
       public Coffee (double id, int dairy, boolean temp )
       {
           sugar = id;
           milk = dairy;
           heat = temp;        
       }


   // (setter)

       public void setSugar(double id){
           sugar = id;
       }
       public void setMilk(int dairy){
           milk = dairy;
       }       
       public void setSize(boolean temp){
           heat = temp;
       }
       //(getter)  
       public double getSugar(){
           return sugar;
       }

       public int getMilk(){
           return milk;
       }

       public boolean temp(){
           return heat;
       }
       //Method to display data, (need to work on this)
       static void display()
       {
           System.out.println("You added +sugar+ tablespoons of sugar to your coffee");
           System.out.println("You have +dairyin your coffee");
           System.out.println("That's a +size+ ounce cup");
        }
        //Default Constructor (need help with setting heat to a default)       
        public Coffee() {
           sugar = 0;
           milk = 0;
          heat = 0;
        }  
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ["Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: SO is not a site for crowdsourcing your homework, and "I would like help" is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Coffee {

    //Instance Variables        
    private double sugar;
    private int milk;
    private boolean isHot; // renamed heat to isHot
    private int size;

    // Constructor       
    public Coffee (double id, int dairy, boolean temp ) {
        sugar = id;
        milk = dairy;
        heat = temp;        
    }

    // (setter)
    public void setSugar(double id) {
        this.sugar = id;
    }
    public void setMilk(int dairy) {
        this.milk = dairy;
    }       
    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setHeat(boolean isHot) {
        this.isHot = isHot;
    }

    //(getter)  
    public double getSugar() {
        return this.sugar;
    }

    public int getMilk() {
        return this.milk;
    }

    public boolean checkIfHot() {
        return this.isHot;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }

    // Method to display data, (need to work on this)
    static void display() {
        System.out.println("You added " + getSugar() + " tablespoons of sugar to your coffee");
        System.out.println("You have " + getMilk() + " in your coffee");
        System.out.println("That's a " + getSize() + " ounce cup");
        System.out.println("Is the cup hot? " + checkIfHot());
    }

    // Default Constructor (need help with setting heat to a default)       
    public Coffee() {
        sugar = 0.0;
        milk = 0;
        heat = false;
        size = 0;
    }  
}
```

Here you go. I have renamed your boolean private member heat to isHot.